# FFmpeg: loop first and last frame in a frame sequence

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a frame sequence of 180 `.png` files named this way:

```
fr_f6a20_0001.png
...
fr_f6a20_0180.png
```

I want to create an `.mp4` file of the sequence, **but making the first and last frame a little longer**.

In plain text, I want to get an output video composed of three concatenated sections:

- 1 second length loop of the first frame (30 frames)
- frame sequence (180 frames)
- 1 second length loop of the last frame (30 frames)

After reading the documentation, I came out with this command:

```bash
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type sequence -i fr_f6a20_%04d.png -filter_complex "[0]loop=30:1:0[first];[0]loop=30:1:180[last];[first][0][last]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[out]" -map "[out]" -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

What I'm getting out of the command:

- 1s loop of the first frame (30 frames)
- frame sequence *rendered THREE TIMES* (180 x 3 frames)
- 1 second length loop of the last frame (30 frames)

I suppose that I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [tpad](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) filter for this.

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type sequence -i fr_f6a20_%04d.png -vf "tpad=start_duration=1:start_mode=clone:stop_duration=1:stop_mode=clone" -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`